# Local extreme point where the function is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement.

Let $f: \mathbf{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbf{R^n}$ and differentiable on $\mathbf{R^n} \setminus \{X\}$ for $X \in \mathbf{R^n}$. If $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} Df(P_k)$ exists for any sequence of points $\{P_k\}_{k \in \mathbf{N}}$ such that $P_k \rightarrow X$ ($P_k \neq X $ for all $k$) and is non-zero, then $X$ is not a local extreme point of $f$.

Could you give me a hint how to go about proving this using elementary calculus.

Comment: We are not assuming $f$ is continuous at $0?$

Comment: The function $f$ is continuous on its entire domain $\mathbf{R^n}$ but the gradient is not defined in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Useful exercise: Suppose $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $\mathbb R $ and differentiable on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$ Suppose $\lim_{t\to 0}g'(t)=L$ where $L$ is finite. Then $g'(0)=L.$ Hint for proof: MVT.

For our problem in $\mathbb R^n:$ Show that the limit hypothesis implies that $\lim_{y\to x} \nabla f(y)=v$ for some nonzero vector $v.$ Consider the function $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ given by $g(t)=f(x+tv).$ Apply the exercise to this function.

Comment: thanks a lot, your hint is really helpful!

Comment: Is my approach right: Lets consider $(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. By MVT there exists $\zeta \in (0,\epsilon)$ such that $f'(\zeta)=\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon-0}$.
Now $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} f'(\zeta)=L$ per definition but also $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)}{\epsilon-0}=f'(0)$, thus $f'(0)=L$.

Comment: That's basically right.